# how to call div from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to call div from javascript function.

I have form tag like this:

```
<form action="save_json.php" id="hazardForm" method="post" onsubmit="displayDiv()">
```

and here is div which I have to call from  displayDiv() function.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="submitPopup">
                    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                        <p data-theme="b" style="color: #30659B">FORM REPORTED
                            SUCCESSFULLY</p>
                        <br> <br> <a href="#initialPage" data-role="button"
                            id="clearHz1" data-theme="b" data-mini="true">OK</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please help me!!

Comment: What do you mean by `call` a `div`?

Comment: `var myDiv = document.getElementById("submitPopup");` from your `displayDiv()` function.

Comment: maybe you mean select instead of *call*.

Comment: `document.getElementById("submitPopup")` or $("#submitPopup")

Comment: You don't call the elements. You select them and manipulate their properties.

Comment: In your CSS put a `display:none;` to your div, with jquery: `$('#submitPopup').css("display", "block");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hazardForm").submit(function()
 {
    $('#submitPopup').show();  
    return false;
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.popup{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="submitPopup" class="popup">
</div>
```